# Sort data from file

Tags: java, file

First of all: Sorry for my English level. I try to learn better.
So, my problem is:
I have a txt file and data in file like this:

1. Hvorostovsky 8(number of songs, i dunno exactly, just for example) Russia.
2. Chaikovsky 9(same here) Russia.

I need to sort by the number of songs from biggest to smallest or from smallest to biggest(it's doesn't matter)
What did I make:

```
public void onMouseClick(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
        char separator = '.';
        ArrayList<String> listOfLines = readFileInArray();
        for(String s: listOfLines){
            char maxValue = '0';
            for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
                if(s.charAt(i) == separator){
                    if(Character.getNumericValue(maxValue) < s.charAt(i + 1)){
                        maxValue = s.charAt(i + 1);
                        System.out.println(maxValue);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I have an ArrayList, that contains data from the file and I figured out how to find the number of songs in the file, but I dunno how I can sort them.

Comment: Why do you split by '.' if the input is "Name 8 Country"?

Comment: @MostNeededRabbit I forgot about it. I added '.' symbol that helps me to find number of songs. Like this: Chaikovsky.8 Russia. I made a cycle where I can check if the symbol equals '.' then i print symbol[i+1] and that's always number of songs.

Comment: So I don't understand if your data that you want to sort is Chaikovsky.8 Russia or Chaikovsky 8 Russia or Chaikovsky.8.Russia

Comment: is it always one digit number?

Comment: It`s doesn't matter. Symbol '.' helps me to find number of songs. I know that I can split by " " in the String class but it will be much harder for me.

Comment: Yes, it`s always one digit number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the description of the input, you can do:

```
 List<String> lines = Arrays.asList("Chaikovsky.9 Russia", "Hvorostovsky.8 Russia", "OtherName.21 Russia");

 List<String> sortedLines = lines.stream()
         .sorted((s1, s2) -> {
            int l1 = s1.indexOf('.') + 1;
            int l2 = s2.indexOf('.') + 1;
            int n1 = Integer.parseInt(s1.substring(l1, s1.indexOf(' ', l1)));
            int n2 = Integer.parseInt(s2.substring(l2, s2.indexOf(' ', l2)));
            return Integer.compare(n1, n2); 
         })
         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Output:

```
[Hvorostovsky.8 Russia, Chaikovsky.9 Russia, OtherName.21 Russia]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Have a nice day :)

Comment: hey again :) How I can compare data like String with your method?  I need to sort countries alphabetically. Here is my code: https://pastebin.com/LNnsKs6P
My data in file now: Chaikovsky.9-Russia

Comment: List<String> sortedLines = lines.stream()
         .sorted((s1, s2) -> {
            int l1 = s1.indexOf('-') + 1;
            int l2 = s2.indexOf('-') + 1;
            return s1.substring(l1).compareToIgnoreCase(s2.substring(l2));
         })
         .collect(Collectors.toList());

Comment: @Staaankey see my comment above ^^

Comment: get an error in the return line with the message "static method may be invoked on containing interface class only". Sorry if I'm bothering you.

Comment: oh, sorry. That was my bad probably, I copied your message again and i can compile it. Thanks again, you saved my life ^^. I can't post a vote again. Thank you very much.

Comment: I`d like to do it, but I have no reputation for it